# symfony3 override fields theme from vich bundle

Tags: twig, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I have installed VichUploaderBundle into my Symfony app and would like to have better control of the appearance of the upload buttons.  I have taken the contents of `fields.html.twig` located in the bundle itself, and copied them into the same file at the path `app/Resources/views/myControllerName/fields.html.twig`  This is also where all the other twig templates are for that set of controllers.

I can not seem to affect anything on the page through this method. Yes I have cleared the cache, I have even removed the cache directory.

Am I placing the file in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2):

You can override that form theme [in many ways](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig), just when you customize `vich_file_widget` and/or `vich_image_widget` e.g.:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block vich_file_widget %}
  {# some content… #}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    {{ form(my_form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the effort @jkucharovic, I was already using the 3rd method you were suggesting. My question was whether or not I put the `fields.html.twig` file in the correct place. Turns out I did not. For others that come along with this question, to override the fields file in the VichUploaderBundle for twig you must put a copy of the `fields.html.twig` file at the following path so that Symfony can override what comes with the bundle.

the fields file is found here and *should not be edited*...

`vendor/vich/uploader-bundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig`

a copy of that file should be placed here in Symfony 3. This file is editable.

`app/Resources/VichUploaderBundle/views/Form/fields.html.twig`